# How to remove double square bracket from around php array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm returning data from a mySQL database into a PHP array but I don't know what is causing the extra square bracket around the whole array.  I've tried playing about with it but I just can't get rid of it.  What I'm after is

> (["0.00"],["0.00"],["0.00"],["1.80"],["0.00"])

But what I'm getting is

> ([["0.00"],["0.00"],["0.00"],["1.80"],["0.00"]])

My PHP is below

```
$queryDate = date("Y-m-d");
$query = "SELECT windspeed FROM `weather_data` WHERE date_format(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d') = '" . $queryDate . "'";

$result = db_query($query);

// If query failed, return `false`
if($result === false) {
  return false;
}

$rows = array();
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
     $rows[] = $row;
  }

echo $_GET['callback']. '('. json_encode($rows) . ')';
```

Please can someone explain what is causing the extra [] and how I can remove them?

Comment: u using `json_encode()`

Comment: You have that output, because thats the json representstion of a multi dimensional array. Its certainly possible to get your desired output, but whats the output to be used for?

Comment: What is the actual query output

Comment: The output is correct. You are putting arrays inside an array.

Comment: you realise you're actually adding `json_encode` right

Comment: I understand that it's an array inside an array, I just don't know how to build a single array.  I'm afraid short comments about json_encode aren't that helpful.  Is there a way to extract the values from the database not in an array, and then put those in a single array?

Answer (score 0):

Each fetched result is an array and you are inserting it inside `$rows` which is an array. That results in a multidimensional array.

You can flatten the multidimensional array after you fetched all the rows and then do a `json_encode()` on it.

So your rows is this before the echo statement:

```
$rows = [["0.00"],["0.00"],["0.00"],["1.80"],["0.00"]];
```

You can flatten it like this:

```
$flattenedRow = array_reduce($rows, function ($a, $b) {
    return array_merge($a, $b);
}, []);
```

So now your `$flattenedRow` is:

```
["0.00","0.00","0.00","1.80","0.00"]
```

And then you can echo it as desired:

```
echo $_GET['callback']. '('. json_encode($flattenedRow) . ')';
```

Comment: Thank you. Is this the only way to do it or can I retrieve the data from mySQL not as an array and then just put them in one array once all retrieved?